# Use Express Router to match a route

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to consolidate a bunch of `route` usage throughout my Express API, and I'm hoping there's a way I can do something like this:

```
const app = express()

const get = {
  fetchByHostname({
    name
  }) {
    return `hey ${name}`
  }
}

const map = {
  '/public/hostname/:hostname': get.fetchByHostname
}

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const url = req.originalUrl
  const args = { ...req.body, ...req.query }
  const method = map[url] // this won't work
  const result = method(args)
  return res.json({
    data: result
  })
})
```

I'm trying to avoid passing round the `req` and `res` objects and just handle the response to the client in one place. Is there an Express/Node/.js module or way to match the URL, like my `map` object above?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve, but from what i can see, your `fectchByHostname({name})`should be `fetchByHostname(name)` and you might be able to return `hey $name`. You should be sure you are using ES6 because with you `args`. Else you have to define the as in es5 `args = {body: req.body, query: req.query};`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm using destructuring. In the `args` object, there would be a key of `name` for me to access inside that method. I came up with a solution in the end.